# Find the sum of first 20 terms $1+2+6+12+36+72+216+\dots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the sum of first 20 terms.   $1+2+6+12+36+72+216+\dots$

Comment: hmmm... I only see 7 terms.

Comment: You have to find other terms

Comment: Yea the pattern is 2 term is twice the first and the third term is thrice the second and fourth term is twice of third and so on

Comment: So you basically have the sum of two sums :
$$
A = \sum_{i=0}^9 6^i\\
B = 2 \cdot \sum_{i=0}^9 6^i = 2A
$$
And you want $A+B$.

Answer (score 3):

This can be viewed as two geometric progressions having their terms in the odd and even positions in the series respectively. We need to find the sum to $10$ terms of each and add them.

The first is,
$$1+6+36+\cdots+$$
$$\text{Sum}=\frac{1\cdot({6^{10}-1})}{6-1}=\frac{6^{10-1}}{{5}}$$
The second is,
$$2+12+72+\cdots+$$
$$\text{Sum}=\frac{2\cdot({6^{10}-1})}{6-1}=\frac{2(6^{10-1})}{{5}}$$

$$\text{Result}=\frac{3}{5}(6^{10}-1)$$

Answer (score 1):

Given the pattern, group the terms as $(1+2)+(6+12)+(36+72)+\ldots$  The sum of each pair is six times the previous, so you can sum the geometric series.

Comment: But it will only work for sum of even number of terms. what about sum of first 19 terms.

Comment: @A---B The question asked about the sum of $20$ terms not the sum of $n$ terms.

Comment: @A---B:  The question asked about $20$ terms, which is even.  One can correct at the end for an odd number of terms.  If we want to sum up to an odd $n$, we can use this to sum to $n-1$, then add in $6^{\frac {n-1}2}$, which is the last term

Answer (score 0):

So the patter appears to be
$a_n=2 a_{n-1}$ when $n$ is even and $a_n=3 a_{n-1}$ when n is odd.
$a_n = 6 a_{n-2}$ in all cases

$\sum_\limits{n=1}^{20} a_n = 1 \sum_\limits{i=0}^9  6^i + 2\sum_\limits{j=0}^9 6^j$

$\frac {3(1-6^{10})}{1-6}$